# node.js to imagemagick command breaking

Tags: javascript, node.js, imagemagick

I'm calling an imagemagick script via node.js and the command is breaking, but I can't figure out why.

A simplified example of exactly what I'm trying to do:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    ls    = spawn('convert', ['-size', '168x45', 'xc:transparent', '-draw', '"image over 0,0 0,0 \'/path/to/img1.png\'"', '/path/to/out.png']);

ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});
```

If I run that exact command (the only thing changed are the paths since they're absolute), I get, on stderr:

```
"convert: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `image over 0,0 0,0 '/path/to/img1.png'' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/3145."
```

Which, according to some forums, usually means that IM can't open the image due to having an invalid path, etc...  Now the odd thing is that if I change the `convert` to `echo` and prepend `convert` I get the following command:

```
convert -size 168x45 xc:transparent -draw "image over 0,0 0,0 '/path/to/img1.png'" /path/to/out.png
```

which works perfectly when run directly from bash.

Any ideas?

more info:

- I just tried this from the directory of the image, and removed the path (so it's `image over ... img1.png`), and I get the same error.
- running `pwd` the same way gives me the appropriate directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer: http://shchekoldin.com/2009/10/13/imagemagick-convert-problem/

Still no clue what's happening, but creating a shell script with simply:

```
eval 'convert '$@
```

and running that as the command (instead of `convert`) solves the issue.  ***wtf???***

Comment: sounds like a problem with convert

Answer (score 1):

Is node.js running as the same user? It could simply be that your user has perms to the file, but the user running node.js doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

From what are you talking you own the hosting ... so it's more likely that apache doesn't have the priviledges to access `/usr/sbin/convert`.

I had this problem and I solved it linking `convert` to `/usr/local/bin` like:

```
ln /usr/sbin/convert /usr/local/bin
```

I changed the path in my scripts and all worked fine.
If that doesn't work and apache still doesn't have access to `/usr/local/bin` directory make a `apache` folder there and give full access to apache on that folder and link `convert` to that folder.

Comment: `which convert` shows `/usr/local/bin/convert` (from within node as well).  And node is running as me (verified via `whoami`)

Comment: @jcolebrand no matter, apache or anything else ... same issue will occur, but it seems that my solution doesn't help him although my suggestion is a good one ..

Answer (score 0):

I believe (without testing) that the problem is the double quotation marks in the argument

```
'"image over 0,0 0,0 \'/path/to/img1.png\'"'
```

What you're aiming for here is to send the entire string as a single argument, instead of the four separate words. However, you're already doing that by having it be a single element in the list of command line arguments. The extra double quotes would actually be interpreted as part of the argument.
So, change the argument to

```
'image over 0,0 0,0 \'/path/to/img1.png\''
```

and you shouldn't need any extra eval command.